# How to access web server running on Palm Pre from another machine?

Tags: webserver, webos

I have a Palm Pre, and I've installed my webserver on it, it listens on port 8080. It works, when I open 192.168.1.104:8080 on the Pre's browser (that's the IP address of the device, I've failed with localhost or 127.0.0.1), it shows images, everything is OK.

But I can't access the webserver from outside, e.g. from my desktop machine, it shows timeout. Is there a firewall on the Pre, or what's wrong? I can change server's port number, if necessary. I didn't configured the Pre, just installed SSH. Also, I can SSH to Pre, and from Pre to my desktop.

**UPDATE:**

*ifconfig* says:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1D:FE:B5:99:51  
          inet addr:192.168.1.104  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:486 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:284 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:69398 (67.7 KiB)  TX bytes:40051 (39.1 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1248 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1248 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:128070 (125.0 KiB)  TX bytes:128070 (125.0 KiB)
```

*iptables -nvL* says:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  370 29404 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 
 1248  128K ALLOWED_PACKETS  all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 INVALID_PACKETS  all  --  !lo    *       127.0.0.0/8          0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:113 flags:0x17/0x02 state NEW reject-with tcp-reset 
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  bridge0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpts:4444:4445 
   47 28580 ALLOWED_PACKETS  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ALLOWED_PACKETS  all  --  bridge0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ALLOWED_PACKETS  all  --  usb0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ALLOWED_PACKETS  icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 0 state NEW 
    0     0 ALLOWED_PACKETS  icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 icmp type 0 
    0     0 ALLOWED_PACKETS  icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 3 state NEW 
    0     0 ALLOWED_PACKETS  icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 icmp type 3 
    0     0 ALLOWED_PACKETS  icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 4 state NEW 
    0     0 ALLOWED_PACKETS  icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 icmp type 4 
    0     0 ALLOWED_PACKETS  icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 5 state NEW 
    0     0 ALLOWED_PACKETS  icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 icmp type 5 
    3   252 ICMPFLOOD  icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 state NEW 
    0     0 ALLOWED_PACKETS  icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 11 state NEW 
    0     0 ALLOWED_PACKETS  icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 icmp type 11 
    0     0 ALLOWED_PACKETS  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:5353 
    0     0 ALLOWED_PACKETS  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:5353 
    0     0 ALLOWED_PACKETS  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3689 
    0     0 ALLOWED_PACKETS  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:3689 
    0     0 ALLOWED_PACKETS  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x04/0x04 
   36  4604 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 3/sec burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix `IPT_PACKET_DROPPED_NO_MATCH: ' 
   36  4604 QUEUE      all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 INVALID_PACKETS  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1541 packets, 166K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ALLOWED_PACKETS (20 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1298  157K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ICMPFLOOD (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    3   252            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           recent: SET name: ICMP side: source 
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           recent: UPDATE seconds: 1 hit_count: 6 TTL-Match name: ICMP side: source limit: avg 1/sec burst 1 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `IPT_ICMPFLOOD: ' 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           recent: UPDATE seconds: 1 hit_count: 6 TTL-Match name: ICMP side: source 
    3   252 ALLOWED_PACKETS  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain INVALID_PACKETS (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 1/sec burst 100 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `IPT_INVALID_PACKETS_DROPPED: ' 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

I assume, TCP should be accepted for port 8080 or whatever I want, just as for 22 (SSH).

Comment: You can run Linux commands as root on the Palm Pre, right? What do `ifconfig` and `iptables -nvL` show?

Comment: I've added the cmd results. I feel a little dumb now, I have very few knowledge about iptables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, incoming traffic is blocked unless explicitly allowed (that's what `policy DROP` means). There are rules to allow “legitimate” traffic, for example the very first rule allows incoming ssh connections (`tcp dpt:22` means TCP traffic to port 22, and that's the ssh port).

The manual way to enable a web server is add an iptables rule that allows incoming traffic to that port. Let's say you want to open port 80. You can to it with the following command:

```
iptables -I INPUT 24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ALLOWED_PACKETS
```

(Note that I'm following the model of ports 3689 and 5353, which allow for things like rate control. Ssh is handled specially, I guess to reduce the risk that a misconfiguration will make it inaccessible.)

There's probably a canonical way to have your settings applied at boot time. Googling [suggests](http://www.webos-internals.org/wiki/Research_iptables_configuration_recommendations) that once you have a satisfactory setting, you can make it permanent with

```
iptables-save >/etc/pmnetconfig/iptables-common.config
```

I don't know WebOS, so I can't confirm the location of this file.

During your experimentations, if you mess up, you can delete a specific rule (e.g. the 42nd) with `iptables -D INPUT 42`. Assuming the location above is correct, you can restore the boot-time settings with

```
iptables-restore </etc/pmnetconfig/iptables-common.config
```